# SSL & Reverse DNS

Tags: ssl, reverse-dns

Just a quick question...I really need an SSL cert in order to make my cell phone work with my mail server. Security is a non-issue, this is just for convenience.

My mail server's FQDN is mail.company.com but a reverse DNS lookup for that address will bring up a different FQDN from a different domain.

Will that be a deal-breaker for SSL based on a cert with a name of mail.company.com or does SSL not really care if an RDNS query returns a different FQDN?

Answer (score 3):

This will not matter for that specific case. SSL/TLS will check that the names in the cert match the hostname you tried to contact, not the reverse one.